# Modal popup to delete object in django

Tags: javascript, python, django

I am using django generic DeleteView() for deleting object from my database. The deleteview is working fine. But I want a alert message before deleting the object.

I have a ListView for showing the objects list in a table. In that table i have a trash icon, when user presses the trash icon it redirects to delete url and deletes the object. But i dont want to go a different page for my deletion instead I want to stay on that list page and want a popup alert message if i want to delete the object. if i click the yes button it deletes the object staying on that page and refreshes the list table.

I have tried several codes for this.

```
<button action="{% url 'employee:employee-delete' employee.id %}" type="button" name="button" class="btn btn-dnager" onclick="document.getElementById('deleteEmployee').style.display='block'">
                                <span data-feather="trash"></span>
                            </button>
<div id="deleteEmployee" class="modal">
          <span onclick="document.getElementById('deleteEmployee').style.display='none'" class="close" title="Close Modal">×</span>
            <div class="modal-content">
                <h1>Delete Account</h1>
                <p>Are you sure you want to delete your account?</p>
            </div>

            {% block footer%}
            {% include 'employee/employee_delete.html' %}
            {% endblock footer %}
        </div>
```

currently I have above code for popup message and trash icon. when the icon is clicked a modal opens.

employee_delete.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% load static %}
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat" rel="stylesheet">

  </head>
  <body>
    {% block footer%}
        <form id="deleteForm" action="" method="post">
          {% csrf_token %}
          <div class="clearfix">
           <button type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('deleteEmployee').style.display='none'" class="cancelbtn">Cancel</button>
           <button type="submit" action="" onclick="document.getElementById('deleteForm').submit();" class="deletebtn">Delete</button>
         </div>
        </form>
    {% endblock footer%}
</body>
</html>
```

above code is for my delete form. Everything is fine but when I click `delete` button nothing happens, doesnt delete the object and gives `Method Not Allowed (POST)` this error.

views.py:

```
class EmployeeDeleteView(DeleteView):
    """
    Deletes a created employee
    """
    template_name = 'employee/employee_delete.html'
    context_object_name = 'employees'
    model = Employee


    def get_object(self):
        id_ = self.kwargs.get("id")
        return get_object_or_404(Employee, id=id_)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        employee = self.get_object()
        #print(employee.errors)
        return render(request, 'employee/employee_delete.html', {'employee': employee})
    

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('employee:employee-list')
```

Comment: can you upload you delete method code from your view.py

Comment: @ngawang13 i have edited with views.py file

Comment: so the model is opening and only the submit button for deletion is not working.

Comment: yes... cancel button and cross button is working as it should work. I think I did not pass submit button url properly

Comment: is you path in you url all fine cause not defining it properly will raise this error sometimes. why are you using onclick function for delete?

Comment: I saw onclick in a tutorial. can you suggest me a better option???

Comment: i think the onclick function is creating the problem. you could do this <button type="submit" class="deletebtn">Delete</button>

Comment: I tried this but same problem. Button is not deleting.