# User role based view in django CBV

Tags: python, django, django-class-based-views

I am using django class based view for my web application. I using django auth class for user sign up and login. In my app, users can be off more than 3 types. Every type of user will have more or less different privilege in the type. I dont know how can I manage different type of users.

So I need advice how can I implement this.

Comment: You can take idea from here https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2018/01/18/how-to-implement-multiple-user-types-with-django.html

Comment: I have read this... But here two types of user handled. My app may have more than three types of user

Comment: Can you have a look this probelm? I am stuck into another problem...https://stackoverflow.com/q/62527476/9955424

Comment: you could create three types of group and make user choose group on creation. With that you could create you own decorator to set permission as per the user in group and use that decorator for each view.

Comment: can i use auth.models.User for user creation???

Comment: how can i assign a user to particular group using signup form?